# Pause map or reduce tasks or chained jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am looking for a way to pause a chained job or a chained task. I want to do this because I want to validate the output of each map or reduce phase, or between each job execution. Is it possible to pause the execution of chained jobs or chained mappers or reducers in MapReduce V2. I was looking for the ChainedMapper and ChainedReducer, but I haven't found anything that could allow me to pause the execution.